# How to stop apache spark streaming job if the stream is ended

Tags: java, apache-spark

If I have a stream that will work for a specific period of time and I have a spark streaming job that will handle this stream,

how could I have the spark streaming job to auto-terminate when the stream stoped sending data?

Comment: First of all, how will the job know that there is no more data forthcoming?

Comment: Consider the stream is date based stream and I know what is the exact date of the last message.